# how can i configure vscode debugger with nuxt 2, typescript and eslint?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, nuxt.js, eslint, vscode-debugger

I did follow some tutorials like ( https://medium.com/js-dojo/debugging-nuxt-js-with-vs-code-60a1a9e75cf6 ), but after setting a breakpoint, it suddenly shift to a different line (ex: in Vue file script tag: clicking on line 40 and suddenly the breakpoint jumps to line 38) and in the "variables" panel in the IDE shows the file chunk compiled code, not the actual source.

My guess is that there is a problem with the source-map setting.

I started with a brand new install of **Nuxt 2.15.8** (using `nuxt-create`), selected **Typescript** as the language and **Eslint**
Also I do use the proper `client: chrome` option when running the debugger for the client-side.

I added the following in `nuxt.config.js`

```js
export default {
  server: {
    port: 8080 // default: 3000
  },
...
  sourceMaps: true,

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
    extend(config, ctx) {
      if (ctx.isDev) {
        config.devtool = ctx.isClient ? 'source-map' : 'inline-source-map';
      }
    },
  },
...
  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
  ],
}
```

here is VSCode `launch.json`

```js
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "client: chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:8080",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "args": ["dev"],
      "name": "server: nuxt",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "osx": {
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/nuxt"
      },
      "linux": {
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/nuxt"
      },
      "windows": {
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js"
      }
    }
  ],
  "compounds": [
    {
      "name": "fullstack: nuxt",
      "configurations": ["server: nuxt", "client: chrome"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Does anyone has a suggestion as to proper configuration so that Nuxt 2, Typescript and eslint can be configured so that VSCode debugger works?